# Why does the function start the sin wave so high along the y-axis?

Tags: jquery, animation, bezier

Take a look at this sine-wave animation. Notice it's start position and end position.

These 2 need to be equal, yet they are not.

I think a solution would be to retain the last used p value from the previous iteration and apply it to the current one.

**Demonstration of image below**: http://jsfiddle.net/WPnQG/4/
[image]

```
function float(dir){
    var x_current = $("div").offset().left;
    var y_current = $("div").offset().top;
    var SineWave = function() {
        this.css = function(p) {
            var s = Math.sin(Math.abs(p-1)*10);
            if (!dir){// flip the sin wave to continue traversing
               s = -s;
            }
            var x =  300 -p * 300;
            var y = s * 100 + 150;
            //var o = ((s+2)/4+0.1); //opacity change
            // add the current x-position to continue the path, rather than restarting
            return {top: y + "px", left: x_current + x + "px"};
        } 
    };

    $("div").stop().animate({
        path: new SineWave
    }, 5000, 'linear', function(){
        // avoid exceeding stack
        // uncomment for this to continue animating
        //setTimeout(function(){float(!dir)}, 0);
    });

}

float(true);
```

Comment: It also jitters at certain points throughout the animation...

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any documentation about the `path` property, but the value of `p` is starting at 1 and gradually transitioning to 0.

Comment: @muistooshort check out the second traversion, it still jumps http://jsfiddle.net/WPnQG/1/ any ideas?

Comment: @Atticus: `p` goes from one to zero and then back to one so you get a discontinuity.